# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError in recursion

Tags: java, function, exception, recursion, biginteger

**Here is the function fact to calculate factorial**

```
static BigInteger fact(BigInteger n)
{
    BigInteger f=BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger temp;
    if(n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) <= 0)
        return f;
    f=f.multiply(n).multiply(fact(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    return f;
}
```

> Input: 1 88888
>
> ```
> Output:
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>   at java.math.BigInteger.multiplyByInt(BigInteger.java:1523)
>   at java.math.BigInteger.multiply(BigInteger.java:1490)
>   at codechef.fact(codechef.java:30)
>   at codechef.fact(codechef.java:30)..... about 100 times
> ```

How can this code run for te<=1000000000 ??

This is my main function:

```
class codechef 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int t=sc.nextInt(); 
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        { 
            int count=0; String te=sc.next();
            BigInteger n=new BigInteger(te); 
            te=fact(n).toString(); 
            for(int j=te.length()-1;j>=0;j--)
            { 
                if(te.charAt(j) == '0')
                { count++; } 
                else break; 
            } 
            System.out.println(count); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

This code is running for input <=1024, suggests edit for >1024...

Comment: Check this >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316833/getting-error-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-stack-size-1036kb-and-outofmemory/37317098#37317098

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you have a maximal recursion depth. If you want to avoid that, you can rewrite the code without recursion. This can be done using a simple loop. It would look something like this (This code is completely untested):

```
static BigInteger fact(BigInteger n){
    BigInteger f = BigInteger.ONE;
    while(n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0) {
        f = f.multiply(n);
        n = n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    return f;
}
```

Comment: Can't be completely tested, because `n` references an immutable `BigInteger` object, so `n.subtract()` doesn't do anything; *unless* you assign return value to something. Did you mean "completely *un*tested"?

Comment: taking very much time for input greater than 10000, any other optimize solution.

Comment: I see no direct and easy approach to optimize this code (but I am no big optimizer myself). There is a [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14456/factorial-algorithm-more-efficient-than-naive-multiplication) on different methods to calculate the factorial of a number. Maybe this can help you.

Comment: Actually problem is not only to calculate factorial, the actual problem is to calculate no of zeros as suffix in factorial. @Leon

Comment: First of all, this is turning into a new, different question, as it no longer is concerned with the StackOverflowError, but now we are searching for faster ways to get to your result. You should do some research on that yourself and don't extend this question to a new topic. To give you are start: To find the numbers of 0 at the end, you need to know how often 5 and 2 occur as prime factors in the numbers less or equal to n. Then just take the minimum of the 2 counts and this is your result, as 2 * 5 = 10 and if you have a zero at the end, it will stay there, no matter how often you multiply.

Comment: Also, if this answer helped or solved your `StackOverflowError` problem (wich seems like it did) please accept it.